# Clustering pixel clots

Tags: clustering

I have:
1) The dark image with few groups of high-brightness pixels and some amount of noise around it.
2) Number of clusters.

Example:
1)
 [image: Image for clustering]

2) 2 clusters

And i need find centers of bright pixel groups.
Centers, in that case, should be placed like this:
[image: Cluster centers on image]


**Question:** Which clustering alghoritm is suitable for this task?

Comment: Do you know in advance how many clusters you have ?

Comment: Yes. In initial data i have the image and number of clusters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If the number of clusters is known** (like here)

You may use Lloyd's clustering [1]

The idea is as follows:
it optimizes a set of cluster centers $p_i$:

```
Initialize the p_i's with an initial guess, or randomly

For each iteration:
   Compute the cluster associated with each p_i,
      (the cluster is the set of points nearer to p_i than to the other p_j's)
   Move each p_i to the weighted centroid of its cluster
```

For an image, the iteration can be implented as follows, computing the mass m_i and the centroid g_i of each cluster:

```
For each i
   m_i = 0
   g_i = (0,0)
For each pixel (x,y) of the image
   let i denote the index of the center p_i nearest to (x,y)
   m_i = m_i + pixel_intensity(x,y)
   g_i = g_i + pixel_intensity(x,y) * (x,y)
For each i
   p_i = (1/m_i)*g_i
```

Since the number of clusters is small, you can find the nearest p_i using a simple loop. If you have a higher number of sites, you may either use a kd-tree, or compute the Voronoi diagram of the sites and iterate on the pixels of each Voronoi cell.

I used this algorithm to cluster the colors of a rubics cube acquired by a lego color sensor, and it works reasonably well while being very easy to implement [3]

**If the number of clusters is unknown**
then the problem is much more difficult.

You may use "mean shift clustering" [2], that will apply a filter-like operation to the image, and make the "modes" appear. It acts like the inverse of a smoothing filter.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_shift

[3] http://alice.loria.fr/WIKI/index.php/Graphite/Lego